# Search closed questions by the number of reopen votes

Tags: support, closed-questions, search, reopen-closed

Is there by any chance a "super ninja" kind of way of searching closed questions by the number of reopen votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earn 10k rep and use the pseudo-mod tools?

Comment: Perhaps a less restrictive answer, if you can :))

Comment: You're saying that like it's hard to get 10k Internet dollars. TheTXI did it, and so can you. In fact, he did it **twice**. That's just insane.

Comment: insane indeed... now for a more sane solution, anyone?

Comment: There are reasons why these sort of tools are hidden behind a 10K wall.

Comment: No doubt there are. Now that we've settled this, any way of jumping this wall, or going around it in this specific case?

Comment: No.  Become a super ninja and you will be allowed to do the super ninja stuff.